# Windows mysql установка

Tags: mysql, windows, install

**Я не могу установить mySQL** на **windows 10**. А мне очень именно mysql. Однажды я его устанавливал, но удалил.

> Так как был молодой глупый.

У меня почему то идет **бесконечная установка**, **что делать?** **Подскажите софт под Windows который решит мою проблему. Или что то по  типу команды which mySQL.**

-Я полностью удалил MySQL с системы. И не могу найти папок где она содержится.

-Я не могу поставить Linux.

-Я не могу выбрать другую базу данных для  проекта.
[image: то что происходит]

Comment: "-Я не могу поставить Linux." Почему? P.S. "Мы следим за тобой, ничтожество."

Comment: Оооо @donRumata это снова ты:D Как то мы с тобой уже переписывались. Потому что HP защищает Windows. Я купил новый ноут бук. И не знал об этом.  Bios перепрошивать и танцевать с бубном я не хочу. И если все навернется. То в ремонт отнести, будет проблемно. Так как проект не готов. Нужен Mysql.

Comment: Ну а Virtualbox чем плох? Поставь туда LAMP и разрабатывай сколько влезет.

Comment: @donRumata мне нужно развернуть node js, laravel, vue, MySQL, MongoDB. Что бы начать полноценно разрабатывать. Я думаю  мой новый компьютер взорвется.

Comment: Ну тогда ищешь на винте все папки\файлы по маске `*mysql*` и тоже самое в реестре. А потом удаляешь. Поможет - гут. Не поможет - ну хз, попробуй прошерстить чем-нить типа `bulk crap uninstaller`. Хотя из всего что ты назвал - я не виже ничего что не запустилось бы на линуксовой виртуалке с 2гб оперативы.